# Definition of connection computed over local vector fields and Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold and $\nabla$ a connection on $M$. If $X$ and $Y$ are smooth vector fields defined on a open set $U$ of $M$ then I define ${ \nabla  }_{ X }Y ={ \nabla  }_{ \widetilde{X} }\widetilde{Y} $ where $\widetilde{X}$ and $\widetilde{Y}$ are global vector fields which extend $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

1. Is this well-defined?, that is, is this definition independent of the vector field extensions?
2. Let ${ E }_{ i }$ form a local frame on $U$. Is this the way that ${ \nabla  }_{ { { E }_{ i } } }{ E }_{ j }$ is defined?
3. If so, then we have that ${ \nabla  }_{ { { E }_{ i } } }{ E }_{ j }={ \nabla  }_{ { \widetilde { E } _{ i } } }{ \widetilde { E }  }_{ j }=\sum _{ k }^{  }{ { \Gamma  }_{ ij }^{ k } } { E }_{ k }$ on $U$, where the ${ \Gamma  }_{ ij }$ are functions defined on $U$ (a.k.a Christoffel symbols). Are the Christoffel symbols independent of the extensions of the the ${ E }_{ i }$?

Comment: Is there a preexisting notion of the covariant derivative of a vector field with respect to a vector field? I have never heard of such a thing, and it can't be expressed in abstract index notation.

Comment: @BenCrowell: The covariant derivative of vector fields wrt vector fields is built in to the [very definition of a connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection#Formal_definition_as_a_differential_operator) in the usual formulation of DG. In index notation $\nabla_X Y$ becomes  $X^i \nabla_i Y^j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To show that this is well-defined, we must take extensions $X_1, X_2$ and $Y_1, Y_2$ of $X$ and $Y$ and show that $\nabla_{X_1} Y_1 |_p = \nabla_{X_2} Y_2 |_p$ for any $p \in U$. Let $V,W$ be open sets such that $p \in V \subset W \subset U$ and construct a smooth bump function $\psi$ such that $\psi|_V = 1$ and $\psi|_{M\setminus W} = 0$. Then $\psi(p)=1$ and $d\psi|_p = 0$, so

$$
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{X_1} Y_1|_p &= \psi(p) \nabla_{X_1}Y_1|_p \\
&=\nabla_{X_1}(\psi Y_1)|_p-(X_1|_p \psi) Y_1|_p \tag{by the Leibniz rule} \\
&= \nabla_{X_1}(\psi Y_1)|_p \tag{since $d\psi|_p=0$} \\
&= \nabla_{X_1}(\psi Y_2)|_p \tag{since $\psi Y_1 = \psi Y_2$} \\
&= \nabla_{\psi X_1}(\psi Y_2)|_p \tag{by $C^\infty$-linearity in $X$} \\
&= \nabla_{\psi X_2}(\psi Y_2)|_p \tag{since $\psi X_1 = \psi X_2$} \\
&= \nabla_{X_2}(\psi Y_2)|_p \\&= \psi(p)\nabla_{X_2} Y_2|_p + (X_2|_p \psi)Y_2|_p \\
&=\nabla_{X_2}Y_2|_p.
\end{align*}$$

2. Yes.
3. Yes, since $\nabla_{E_i} E_j$ is independent of the extension and the formula $\nabla_{E_i} E_j = \sum_k \Gamma_{ij}^k E_k$ uniquely determines the $\Gamma_{ij}^k$. You can see this by letting $\theta^i$ denote the dual frame to $E_i$ (i.e. $\theta^j(E_i) = \delta^j_i$) and showing $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \theta^k(\nabla_{E_i} E_j)$.

Comment: I´m very grateful with you.

Comment: I think you mean that ${ \psi  }_{ |M-W }=0$, so that $\psi$ is a function defined on all $M$. Also I think that in the 3rd "since" it should read $\psi { X }_{ 1 }=\psi { X }_{ 2 }$, right?.

Comment: I was thinking that there may be not vector field extensions of the ${ E }_{ i }$ over $U$ at all!!!. Instead you pick $V\subseteq W\subseteq\ U$ and a bump function $\phi$ such that ${ \phi  }_{ |V}=1$ and ${ \phi  }_{ |U-W }=0 $, take $\phi { E }_{ i }$ and the extend it by the zero section. This global vector field is smooth and coincides with ${ E }_{ i }$ on $V$, but not necesarilly on $U$. So how can we see that with respect to this kind of extensions the covariant derivative is independent?? I´m so sorry of asking again. Should I edit the original question?

Comment: @Mr.X Thanks for the corrections, I've edited my answer. I'm not sure you're following the idea of the argument in your last objection - the whole bump function argument is just to show that the extension doesn't matter. We use a different $V,W,\psi$ for each point $p\in U$.